# why does this code go into infinite loop?

Tags: python, datetime, infinite-loop, python-datetime, timedelta

i don't understand why this snippet goes into a loop

```
def difference():
    for p, j in enumerate(listaDivisa[:-1]):
        if j[2] == listaDivisa[p + 1][2]:
            if j[3] == "ON" and listaDivisa[p + 1][3] == "OFF":
                time1= j[1]
                time2= listaDivisa[p + 1][1]
                d1 = datetime.strptime(time1, '%H:%M:%S')
                d2 = datetime.strptime(time2, '%H:%M:%S')

                diff = d2 - d1
                return diff
```

listaDivisa looks like this:

```
['2009-10-16', '21:06:34.00044', 'kitchen sensor', 'ON']
['2009-10-16', '21:13:22.00016, 'kitchen sensor', 'OFF']
['2009-10-16', '12:53:29.00004', 'bathroom sensor', 'ON']
['2009-10-16', '14:02:51.00056, 'bathroom sensor', 'OFF']

...
```

also, i tried printing time1 and time2 but it prints 08:50:00 and 08:55:00 for every elements and it's not correct but when i omit the return statement it prints the correct values even thought it goes in a loop

Comment: There is no infinite loop. The loop will run max `len(listaDivisa[:-1])` times and might even be finished earlier if the `return` is hit.

Comment: I would recommend making `listaDivisa` an argument to your `difference` function. That makes debugging easier, since you can feed your function different dummy values of `listaDivisa` to see what happens.

Comment: @Matthias can you tell me please what's wrong with this code then? because it doesn't give any error or print anything, neither "Process finished..." so i assumed it went in an infinite loop

Comment: @jjramsey ok i'll try it

Comment: If it had gone into an infinite loop, the function would never finish running without some interrupting signal (for example, pressing Ctrl-C at the Python interpreter prompt, or killing your Python script).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors with your code.
First, the input you provided is weird, is it a nested list? In the code below I assume is a nested list.
Second, the time format is wrong, your input contains millisecond but you pass `"%H:%M:%S"` to `datetime.strptime`, you will get an error. The correct format in this case is `"%H:%M:%S.%f"`.

Here is the correct implementation. I commented out the print calls that helped me with the debugging.

```
from datetime import datetime

  
def difference(nested_list):
    for p, j in enumerate(nested_list[:-1]):
        #print(f'processing entry {p}')
        if j[2] == nested_list[p + 1][2]:
            if j[3] == "ON" and nested_list[p + 1][3] == "OFF":
                time1= j[1]
                time2= nested_list[p + 1][1]
                d1 = datetime.strptime(time1, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
                d2 = datetime.strptime(time2, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
                diff = d2 - d1
                #print(f'returning {diff}')
                return diff
    #print('finished without returning anything')

nested_list = [
    ['2009-10-16', '21:06:34.00044', 'kitchen sensor', 'ON'],
    ['2009-10-16', '21:13:22.00016', 'kitchen sensor', 'OFF'],
    ['2009-10-16', '12:53:29.00004', 'bathroom sensor', 'ON'],
    ['2009-10-16', '14:02:51.00056', 'bathroom sensor', 'OFF'],
]

result = difference(nested_list)
print(result) #datetime.timedelta(seconds=407, microseconds=999720)
```